# undefined method `lookup_asset_for_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I just updated a Rails 4 app to Rails 4.2 and when I attempt to load up the app I get the following error (with stack trace):

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `lookup_asset_for_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff78e8d5468>:0x007ff78e8dfc10>
Did you mean?  lookup_context:
  sprockets_better_errors (0.0.4) lib/sprockets_better_errors/sprockets_rails_helper.rb:85:in `check_errors_for'
  sprockets_better_errors (0.0.4) lib/sprockets_better_errors/sprockets_rails_helper.rb:72:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
  sprockets_better_errors (0.0.4) lib/sprockets_better_errors/sprockets_rails_helper.rb:71:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
  app/views/employers/sessions/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_employers_sessions_new_html_erb__3069494963734045487_70350612585440'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  responders (2.1.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:236:in `default_render'
  responders (2.1.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
  responders (2.1.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
  responders (2.1.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
  responders (2.1.1) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:205:in `respond_with'
  devise (3.5.6) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:12:in `new'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:815:in `call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack-reverse-proxy (0.10.0) lib/rack_reverse_proxy/roundtrip.rb:19:in `call'
  rack-reverse-proxy (0.10.0) lib/rack_reverse_proxy/middleware.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/server.rb:557:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/server.rb:404:in `process_client'
  puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
  puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

When the web console opens on the page it points to my `stylesheet_link_tag` as the culprit:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "employers-auth", media: "all" %>
```

I tried removing it to see what would happen, at which point I received the same error in relation to my `javascript_include_tag`. I've been searching for resources on this issue but haven't turned up much.

I've started working through my Gemfile upgrading my gems to see if that helps, but so far it hasn't. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 4.1"
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'puma'
gem 'resque', "~> 1.22.0", require: 'resque/server'
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.5.0.1'

gem 'aws-sdk-v1', '~> 1.66.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'delayed_paperclip'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.1.1'
group :production do
    # Needs to be placed before paperclip-optimizer
    # gem 'image_optim_bin'
    gem 'image_optim'
    gem 'image_optim_pack'
end
gem 'paperclip-optimizer'

gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'twitter-text'
gem 'koala' # for Facebook Graph API
gem 'mimemagic'
gem 'linkedin'

gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.1'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0' # Note: You MUST use 5.0.0 or greater for Rails 4.0+
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

# For Mail
gem 'gibbon', '~> 1.2.0'
# gem 'newrelic_rpm' # Clashes with Resque (See issue #180 on GitHub)
gem 'intercom-rails', "~> 0.2.28" # This gem makes the Javascript API and Messenger available
gem 'intercom', "~> 2.5.4" # This gem is for sending events/attributes from the backend.

# for the blog
gem "rack-reverse-proxy", :require => "rack/reverse_proxy"

# For CMS
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails', '~> 0.12.1'

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'heroku_rails_deflate'
    gem 'rack-timeout'
    gem 'exception_notification'
end

group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'sprockets_better_errors'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem 'factory_girl'
    gem 'valid_attribute'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

And here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    active_model_serializers (0.8.3)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
    activejob (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.5.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    angular-ui-bootstrap-rails (0.12.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.3.3.1)
      execjs
    aws-sdk-v1 (1.66.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    buftok (0.2.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capybara (2.6.2)
      addressable
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.0)
    database_cleaner (1.5.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    delayed_paperclip (2.9.1)
      paperclip (>= 3.3)
    devise (3.5.6)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    domain_name (0.5.20160216)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    dotenv (2.1.0)
    dotenv-rails (2.1.0)
      dotenv (= 2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.0, < 5.1)
    equalizer (0.0.10)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (4.1.4)
      actionmailer (~> 4.0)
      activesupport (~> 4.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    exifr (1.2.4)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.6.3)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    font-awesome-rails (4.5.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    friendly_id (5.0.5)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    fspath (2.1.1)
    gibbon (1.2.1)
      httparty
      multi_json (>= 1.9.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    hashie (3.4.3)
    heroku_rails_deflate (1.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.13)
      rack (>= 1.4.5)
    http (1.0.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0)
      http-form_data (~> 1.0.1)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    http-form_data (1.0.1)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    httparty (0.13.7)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    image_optim (0.22.1)
      exifr (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
      fspath (~> 2.1)
      image_size (~> 1.3)
      in_threads (~> 1.3)
      progress (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.1)
    image_optim_pack (0.2.1.20160221)
      fspath (~> 2.1)
      image_optim (~> 0.19)
    image_size (1.4.2)
    in_threads (1.3.1)
    intercom (2.5.4)
      json (~> 1.8)
    intercom-rails (0.2.30)
      activesupport (> 3.0)
    jbuilder (1.5.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (4.1.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.1)
    koala (2.2.0)
      addressable
      faraday
      multi_json
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    linkedin (1.1.0)
      hashie (~> 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      oauth (~> 0.4)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    memoizable (0.4.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.99.1)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    naught (1.1.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    oauth (0.5.0)
    oauth2 (1.1.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0, < 1.5.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.3.1)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (3.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-linkedin (0.2.0)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-twitter (1.2.1)
      json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.1)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.3.5)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
    paperclip-optimizer (2.0.0)
      image_optim (~> 0.19)
      paperclip (>= 3.4)
    pg (0.18.4)
    progress (3.1.1)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-rails (0.3.4)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    puma (2.16.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-proxy (0.5.17)
      rack
    rack-reverse-proxy (0.10.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-proxy (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.14)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rack-timeout (0.3.2)
    rails (4.2.5.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.5.0)
    redis (3.2.2)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    responders (2.1.1)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    resque (1.22.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.0)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    resque-scheduler (2.2.0)
      redis (>= 3.0.0)
      resque (>= 1.20.0, < 1.25)
      rufus-scheduler (~> 2.0)
    rspec-core (3.4.3)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.4.1)
    rufus-scheduler (2.0.24)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.22)
    sass (3.4.21)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    simple_oauth (0.3.1)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.6.3)
    sprockets (3.5.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets_better_errors (0.0.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.2)
    twitter (5.16.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      buftok (~> 0.2.0)
      equalizer (= 0.0.10)
      faraday (~> 0.9.0)
      http (~> 1.0)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      memoizable (~> 0.4.0)
      naught (~> 1.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.3.0)
    twitter-text (1.13.3)
      unf (~> 0.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
    valid_attribute (2.0.0)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    will_paginate (3.1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.8.1)
  angular-ui-bootstrap-rails (~> 0.12.1)
  aws-sdk-v1 (~> 1.66.0)
  better_errors
  bootstrap-sass
  capybara
  database_cleaner
  delayed_paperclip
  devise
  dotenv-rails
  exception_notification
  factory_girl
  faker
  font-awesome-rails (~> 4.5.0.1)
  friendly_id (~> 5.0.0)
  gibbon (~> 1.2.0)
  heroku_rails_deflate
  image_optim
  image_optim_pack
  intercom (~> 2.5.4)
  intercom-rails (~> 0.2.28)
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails (~> 4.1)
  koala
  launchy
  linkedin
  mimemagic
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-linkedin
  omniauth-twitter
  paperclip (~> 4.3.1)
  paperclip-optimizer
  pg
  pry-rails
  puma
  rack-reverse-proxy
  rack-timeout
  rails (= 4.2.5.1)
  rails_12factor
  responders (~> 2.1.1)
  resque (~> 1.22.0)
  resque-scheduler
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.4)
  shoulda-matchers
  spring
  sprockets_better_errors
  twitter
  twitter-text
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  valid_attribute
  web-console (~> 2.0)
  will_paginate (~> 3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.11.2
```

Here is my `application.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module MyApp
    class Application < Rails::Application
        # Turn on GZIP compression
        config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater

        config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
        I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = true
        config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/partials"
        config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
        config.assets.image_optim = false

        # Precompile additional assets.
        # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
        config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
        config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts", "employers")

        # CSS Assets for precompilation
        config.assets.precompile += %w(
            framework_and_overrides.css
            employers-overrides.css
            employers.css
            employers-auth.css
            profiles.css
            global-widget.css
            style-widget.css
            widget.css
            profile-builder.css
            font-awesome.min.css
        )
        # JS Assets for precompilation
        config.assets.precompile += %w(
            angular-animate.js
            angular.min.js
            query-parser.js
            debounce.js
            column-resizer.js
            window-resize
            application.js
            employer-app.js
            app.js
            widget-app.js
            jquery.min.js
            twitter-text
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: what does your ```config/initializers/assets.rb``` file look like? You will have to add ```employers-auth``` there if you intend to use it like you describe

Comment: Right now it's just: `Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'`. I've added it to `config.assets.precompile` in `application.rb` though, along with all my other assets.

Comment: Did you solve this? It's killing me!

Comment: I did solve it eventually but I don't remember what the solution was since it was so long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, your problem likely is derived from not using the assets precompile correctly.

If you have `employers-auth.js` and `employers-auth.css` files you intend to use with stylesheet and javascript include tags, you will need to do the following

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(employers-auth.css employers-auth.js)
```

Whatever you were doing with assets in your `config/application.rb` undo it. And you will need to restart your server

Comment: That had no effect. I don't have an `employers-auth.js`, only `employers-auth.css.scss`. I'll copy/paste `application.rb` into my question so you get the whole file. Also I tried just deleting that `stylesheet_link_tag` from my template, but it just hits the next one. If I remove all instances of `stylesheet_link_tag` it hits my first `javascript_include_tag`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The error was coming from sprockets_better_errors. I removed the offending gem and never looked back :)